# How do I exclude a file (eg config file) in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

- https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack
- https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack

I've tried:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.merge({
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: {
                    exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "public/my-config.js")]
                }
            }]
        }
    })
}
```

Or

```
config.module.rule('js')
  .exclude({
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/my-config.js")
  })
```

But it doesn't work.

I want to either import `public/my-config.js` with script tag in the `pages/index.html` or just `import { config1, config2 } from '../public/my-config'`.

I was able to use `externals` to not include a module in webpack though, but it's not quite intuitive with Vue.js.

I must have the `my-config.js` be available at `dist/` so that it can be edited.

Comment: In Vue CLI projects, the `public` dir contains files that are [only copied](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling), not processed by webpack, which seems to be what you want. And it wouldn't make sense to exclude it from processing, since that should already be done. What are you really trying to exclude the file from?

Comment: @tony19 Yes. Thanks for the link to the Vue documentation. I was able to check with `vue inspect > output.js` that there is `CopyWebpackPlugin` that has `from: '/path/to/my_project/public', to: '/path/to/my_project/dist'` and `ignore: ['index.html', '.DS_Store']`. What I want to do is to not include the `my-config.js` file, but have `my-config.js.gitkeep` file and let the user create his/hers own `my-config.js` file by copying the file `cp my-config.js.gitkeep my-config.js`. I'll be using my own `my-config.js` file as well.

Comment: It may not matter if I have the whole `dist/` and `public/my-config.js` in `.gitignore` which is the case, but I want to know about how to exclude a file, well, I guess specifically those that are in the `public` directory.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to:

- https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain#config-plugins-modify-arguments
- https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#ignore

What I wrote in my `vue.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    baseUrl: ".",
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.plugin('copy').tap((args) => [[
              {
                from: '/path/to/my_project/public',
                to: '/path/to/my_project/dist',
                toType: 'dir',
                ignore: [
                  'index.html',
                  '.DS_Store',
                  'config.data.js'
                ]
              }
          ]]
        );
    }
}
```

I used `$ vue inspect > output.js` then examined the `output.js` file for what arguments were used for the `config.plugin('copy')` which happens to be an instance of `new CopyWebpackPlugin`.

Answer (score 3):

Reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2231#issuecomment-413441633

Try this, much simpler:

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('copy').tap(([options]) => {
      options[0].ignore.push('api/**/*')
      return [options]
    })
  }
}
```