# Importing static local json file to Vue store (exclude from build)

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm trying to have my add data from a local static JSON file to the Vue vuex store.

I want my JSON file separated from the bundle process, so that i can change the content anytime in future, without rebuilding the whole site.

I have my json file [test.json] in the `public` folder

And with the following code, i managed to import the data, but its still being bundled on build of the site.

```
import data from '../public/test';

export const state = () => ({
  allData: {}
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_ALL_DATA(state, data) {
    state.allData = data
  }
}

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
    commit('SET_ALL_DATA', data)
  }
}
```

I have also tried hosting the JSON file on a web server and doing an axios call to it on `nuxtServerInit` like so. but the called upon json file still gets bundled, as changing the hosted json file does nothing to update the content.

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { $axios }) {
    const res = await $axios.$get('https://www.amq.fariskassim.com/testjson/test.json')
    commit('SET_ALL_DATA', res)
  }
}
```

I'm all out of solutions so if anyone can point me in the right direction, i would be totally grateful

Comment: The axios approach should work - did you then remove the `.json` file from `public`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I exclude a file (eg config file) in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035036/how-do-i-exclude-a-file-eg-config-file-in-vue-js)