# How to assign "IP address" to variable from json file in "vuejs"

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a project (or 2 actually) where a frontend server is talking/requesting data from a backend server (written in Python). Now when I build and distribute the dist I also define the ip-address to the backend. This is not dynamic and i have to change ip and build again for every distribution (new IP-address).
My wish is to be able to set the ip-address to backend-server, if default coded address is wrong (usually) via a data.json file that is looking like this

```
[{"FRONTEND_IP": "192.168.1.35" },{"BACKEND_IP": "192.168.1.123" }]
```

There is a ton of samples on how to read .json files from within code base and I have discovered that i can import file into a variable, like this

```
import posts from '../../data.json'
```

And use it as the array of json data it is.
My problem is that when I build with

```
npm run build
```

it (the data.json file) gets included into the dist package hence I can't change the IP.

Have you got any tips on how to solve my problem with an external config file outside the dist compilation

/a

Answer (score 1):

You can read the source IP from a txt file so that you can change it whenever you want.

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./data.json', function read(err, data) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
}
const content = data;

loadIp(content);
});

function loadIp(content) {
```

Comment: Hi Sabri, tried with your advice as this
'''
onMounted(async () => {
      
      console.log("onMounted ")
      console.log("Backend:", BACKEND_PATH.value)


      const fs = require('fs');

      fs.readFile("./posts.json", function read(err, data){

        console.log("read error", err)

        console.log("data", data)
      });
     });
but got a bunch of errors, main is "TypeError: e.readFile is not a function"

Comment: Found a combined solution to above question. Exclude in vue.config.js and read as either import (my test) or as Sabri says.
Exclude like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035036/how-do-i-exclude-a-file-eg-config-file-in-vue-js